# Cargo fails to build when invoked from inside a python script

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a python script which will symlink my binary into `/usr/bin`, and I wanted to add the functionality of building the binary if it is not already built.

```py
# Check if binary exists
if path.exists(src_bin):
    # If not, build it
    run('cargo build --release', shell=True, check=True)
# Check if symlink already exists
if path.exists(dest_bin):
    # Remove it, in case it is outdated
    path.remove(dest_bin)
# Symlink binary to /usr/bin
os.symlink(src_bin, dest_bin)
```

But the cargo command (which works perfectly fine if I run it in the terminal) errors out with this:

```
no override and no default toolchain set; run 'rustup default stable' to set the stable toolchain as default
```

My best guess is that `cargo` relies on some environment variables to tell it which toolchain to use which are not present in the python environment, but I don't know what variables those might be. I also tried

```py
run(['cargo', 'build', '--release'], check=True)
```

but the same thing happened.

What is causing this, and is there a way around it?

**Edit** more info:

```sh
$ ls ~/.cargo/bin
# no output
$ ls ~/.rustup/toolchains
stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
$ which cargo
/usr/bin/cargo
```

I tried

```py
run('rustup run stable cargo build --release', shell=True, check=True)
```

and got

```
error: toolchain 'stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu' is not installed
```

when I run `cargo build --release` or `rustup run stable cargo build --release` in the shell, both build sucessfully.

Comment: It means you're either: 1). Not properly sourcing rustup in the default shell, 2). Haven't installed a toolchain, or 3). For some reason, rustup isn't using the proper defaults. A trivial fix is `rustup run stable cargo build --release`, which should fix this. But it's verbose, so running `rustup default stable` should make this the default in all cases. Can you run `rustup show` to show the installed toolchains?

Comment: Normally, rustup works by installing toolchains to `~/.rustup/toolchains/` and then the default is found under `~/.cargo/bin`, which is added to the path. If that hasn't been added to the path, or you have no toolchains installed and `cargo` isn't under `~/.cargo/bin`, you're going to have this error.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh On my system `cargo` is installed in `/usr/bin`. `~/.cargo/bin` is empty. I have run `rustup default stable`.

Comment: When I run `rustup run stable cargo build --release` I get `error: toolchain 'stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu' is not installed` even though that toolchain definitely is installed.

Comment: Then the issue is you have both a system `cargo` from a package manager installed while also using `rustup`. You can remove one or the other. You should probably remove your system installation and install the toolchain via `rustup`, since that is the preferred way to install Rust. You can use `rustup show` to list the installed toolchains.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh `sudo pacman -R cargo` failed because `cargo` was not installed with `pacman` (I'm on arch). The only way I remember installing `cargo` is with `rustup`.

Comment: Did you install it via AUR or from the Rust site using a binary? To my knowledge, rustup hasn't installed to `/usr/bin` ever, or at least in a very long time.